# Multiplying a selection of columns by another selection in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create new columns in a data frame from the products of multiplying one selection of columns with another. E.g:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1:6, 3), nrow = 3,
                           dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:6])))
df

 A data.frame: 3 × 6 
 a  b   c   d   e   f 
 
 1  4   1   4   1   4 
 2  5   2   5   2   5 
 3  6   3   6   3   6

df <- df %>% mutate(df$a:df$c * df$d:df$f)
df

 A data.frame: 3 × 6 
 a  b   c   d   e   f   a*d a*e a*f b*d b*e b*f c*d c*e c*f
 
 1  4   1   4   1   4     4   1   4  16   4  16   4   4  16
 2  5   2   5   2   5    10   4  10  25  10  25  10   4  10
 3  6   3   6   3   6    12   9  12  36  18  36  18   9  18
```

I want to find an easy general way to create product columns and add to the dataset.
In the example I try to multiply columns `a`, `b` and `c` with columns `d`, `e` and `f` and add all possible combinations to the dataframe. The syntax above obviously doesn't work, so I want to find the easiest solution to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not simple, this is easy enough.

```r
# the data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1:6, 3), nrow = 3,
                           dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:6])))

library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

# set the column groups you want to multiply
cols1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
cols2 <- c("d", "e", "f")

# create the multiplication expressions.
col_mult <- set_names(c(outer(cols1, cols2, paste, sep = "*")))
col_expr <- parse_exprs(col_mult)

# use the !!! operator to execute them all
df %>% 
  mutate(!!!col_expr)
```

Which gives the following:

```r
  a b c d e f a*d b*d c*d a*e b*e c*e a*f b*f c*f
1 1 4 1 4 1 4   4  16   4   1   4   1   4  16   4
2 2 5 2 5 2 5  10  25  10   4  10   4  10  25  10
3 3 6 3 6 3 6  18  36  18   9  18   9  18  36  18
```

---

If you were doing this a lot in complex cases, you could go all out with it and make a function so that you can use the tidyselect helpers. Again, not the most simple thing, but it would fit the bill of a "general way".

```r
mutate_product <- function(df, cols_x, cols_y) {
  .cols_x <- names(tidyselect::eval_select(enexpr(cols_x), df))
  .cols_y <- names(tidyselect::eval_select(enexpr(cols_y), df))
  
  col_mult <- set_names(c(outer(.cols_x, .cols_y, paste, sep = "*")))
  col_expr <- parse_exprs(col_mult)
  
  mutate(df, !!!col_expr)
}

df %>% 
  mutate_product(a:c, starts_with("d"))
#   a b c d e f a*d b*d c*d
# 1 1 4 1 4 1 4   4  16   4
# 2 2 5 2 5 2 5  10  25  10
# 3 3 6 3 6 3 6  18  36  18
```

Comment: Thanks, for providing code for making it into a function. I am indeed looking for a solution that's easy to use in complex cases. From the replies I've received there obviously no straightforward way to do this. I was wondering though: Why the three exclamation marks in the last line (`mutate(!!!col_expr)`)?

Comment: Here is some documentation: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html. Basically what it is saying is to take the list, and make each entry a comma separated entry into mutate, and evaluate it. So that is basically doing `mutate(df, col_expr[[1]], col_expr[[2]], ...)`, but evaluating each item so it works (i.e., not just swapping in text).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `!!!` operator essentially tells mutate to sequentially create each product variable by multiplying the respective columns in `df`..?

Comment: Yes. We built the R code basically (which is simple here) and are executing it. The list item name will be the new variable name. The new variable value will be as from executing the list item value. The !!! will run through the list sequentially doing just that.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in base R with:

```r
cbind(df, setNames(outer(1:3, 4:6, function(x, y) df[x] * df[y]),
                   as.vector(outer(letters[1:3], letters[4:6], paste, sep = " * "))))

#>   a b c d e f a * d b * d c * d a * e b * e c * e a * f b * f c * f
#> 1 1 4 1 4 1 4     4    16     4     1     4     1     4    16     4
#> 2 2 5 2 5 2 5    10    25    10     4    10     4    10    25    10
#> 3 3 6 3 6 3 6    18    36    18     9    18     9    18    36    18
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol = 6, nrow = 3)), letters[1:6])

df
#>   a b c d e f
#> 1 1 4 1 4 1 4
#> 2 2 5 2 5 2 5
#> 3 3 6 3 6 3 6
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful that your solution can be accomplished without any additional packages. Could it be solved so that I don't need to know the variables position?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try

```
p <- data.frame(
  lapply(
    df[4:6],
    function(x) x * df[1:3]
  )
)

cbind(
  df,
  setNames(p, gsub("(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\2*\\1", names(p)))
)
```

which gives

```
  a b c d e f a*d b*d c*d a*e b*e c*e a*f b*f c*f
1 1 4 1 4 1 4   4  16   4   1   4   1   4  16   4
2 2 5 2 5 2 5  10  25  10   4  10   4  10  25  10
3 3 6 3 6 3 6  18  36  18   9  18   9  18  36  18
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Would you care to explain what `"(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\2*\\1"` in the `gsub` function does?

Comment: @PålBjartan That is just to change the order of substrings in the column names of `p`

Comment: Hmm, ok. I am trying to understand how the code works, and admittedly this is Greek to me. If you could elaborate a tad more or link to a page that does, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @PålBjartan This is regex in R. You can have a quick look at https://regenerativetoday.com/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-regular-expressions-in-r/. If you want to learn more about `gsub`, you can type `?gsub` and try the examples there :)

Comment: @PålBjartan Another helpful source might be https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/, and you can see there is a cheatsheet for regular expression, which is a pdf document. You can read that.